# Dell U271 monitor DisplayPort suddenly not working

Tags: mac, display, displayport

My new(ish) Dell U271 took a bit of a knock and it now suddenly doesn't recognise the Macbook plugged into it via DisplayPort - this had been working great for several months up until now.

When I "Scan Sources", it doesn't find anything on DisplayPort.  However, one suspicious behaviour leads me to think all might not be lost.  When the Mac is woken from sleep, this used to kick the monitor in (as an monitor would) and while it no longer does that, the light on the monitor does go from standby orange to blue briefly, then the monitor says it's going into "power save" mode.  It seems like it gets *some* kinda signal.

Any ideas on how I can diagnose the problem?  I'm trying to find another mac but no one near me has one ...

Comment: try another adapter too

Comment: Note that issues with DisplayPort input only seem to be a rather common issue with U2711 models. I had one that went repeatedly black for a second or two before coming back. This went on for weeks before the DisplayPort input failed completely and it had to be replaced. So if it was just the connector for you, you've been lucky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple/stupid answer in the end, thought I'd add for completeness.  I replaced the cable (not an "adapter", just a straight cable) and it suddenly started working.  Who'd have thought that a cable that never moves could suddenly stop working ...